# UIAppearance Customizing UITabBarItem using a category/extension is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem, objective-c-category, uiappearance

I have a custom category on `UITabBarItem` that lets me customize the badge properties. All my code related to the functionality of that is working fine.

However, `UIAppearance` is not working.

My methods never get called and if I add `[[UITabBarItem appearance] customBadgeBackgroundColor]` to my `appDelegate` it crashes with an `NSInvalidArgument` error deep in the iOS SDK. If I add this method later in my app nothing happens and the invocations for `UITabBarItem` are null.

`setCustomBadgeBackgroundColor:` is never called.

I have attached the relevant and minimal code for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UITabBarItem+CustomBadge.h**

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITabBarItem (CustomBadge)

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIColor *customBadgeBackgroundColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; UIAppearance doesn't work

@end
```

**UITabBarItem+CustomBadge.m**

```c
#import "UITabBarItem+CustomBadge.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UITabBarItem (CustomBadge)

- (UIColor *)customBadgeBackgroundColor
{
    UIColor *customBadgeBackgroundColor = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(customBadgeBackgroundColor));
    if (!customBadgeBackgroundColor) {
        return [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        return customBadgeBackgroundColor;
    }
}

- (void)setCustomBadgeBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)customBadgeBackgroundColor
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(customBadgeBackgroundColor), customBadgeBackgroundColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

    UILabel *customBadgeLabel = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(customBadgeValue));
    customBadgeLabel.backgroundColor = customBadgeBackgroundColor;
}

@end
```

Full source code can be found here. https://github.com/valleyman86/UITabBarItem-CustomBadge